# How to check if a directory is inside other directory

Tags: java, path, filesystems

How can I check if a given file is under other file? For example, I have `new Paths.get("/foo/bar/")` and `new Paths.get("./abc/def.jar")`.
And I want to check whether the second is under `/foo/bar`.

I can figure out some string based comparisons like `path.toFile().getAbsolutePath().startsWith(path2.toFile().getAbsolutePath())`, but that looks fragile and not right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found this useful [`Path.startsWith( Path other )`](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/Path.html#startsWith%28java.nio.file.Path%29) method, so this worked for me:

```
inputPath.toAbsolutePath().startsWith(outputDirectory.toAbsolutePath())
```