# Java regex match part of path

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check if a chosen path is a valid path for my Java program. In order to be valid, it must match the path `E:\test\(someFolderName)\`. The chosen folder can be deeper in that directory.

This is what I have tried:

```
String a = "E:\\test\\anotherFolder";
if (a.matches("E:\\\\btest\\b\\.*")) {
    System.out.println("match");
}
```

I have also tried putting `test` into `[]` but it did not work.

`\b` would mark the beginning of a word boundary, and adding `\b` again should close it, correct?

`.*` would match any character 1 to infinite times.

So, is there a problem with the escaping? Or do I need to group it differently?

Comment: Not really the way to do it. You should really be using something like ```java.nio.file.Path.getParent()```

Comment: Possibly related: [Java: How to check if a directory is inside other directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26518033)

Comment: This pattern will match whatever the last folder in the path is: "E:(?:\\\w+)*\\(.*)\\", see [here](https://regex101.com/r/17YEl7/1) for examples. As has been said, though, there are probably better was to deal with this.

Comment: I don't know, why this questions was closed again :-( So here's only a few things via comments :-/ Your `.` is escaped, so it matches stricly only a `.`, not <any character>. Then, `.*` (not escacped dot) _would_ match 0..* times, not 1..* times.. You should not use word boundary `\b` after `test`, because it doesn't make sense. If you want a backslash, match a backslash. Matching a backslash requires 4 backslashes (that's `\\\\ `.). The other comments are very valid: You should use `getParent()`. "test" in `[]` doesn't make sense, read the docs.

Comment: yeah exactly, people are so ignorant "yeah that thing was definitely answered somewhere else" Bruh, its not only about the backslashes here. Thanks for your answer! : 3

Answer (score -1):

Possible duplicated of [escaping-special-characters-in-java-regular-expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664434/escaping-special-characters-in-java-regular-expressions).

You need more backslashes. "The 4 slashes in the Java string turn into 2 slashes in the regex pattern. 2 backslashes in a regex pattern matches the backslash itself.".

Comment: But I have 4 backslashes?

Comment: @Dahlin No, you have not. You have 2 backslashes to match a backslash. The next 2 backslashes are for `\b`, word boundary, that you do not even need here.